# Laravel toastr message not working

Tags: php, laravel, toastr

**Laravel** *toastr message* not working

I have added package  `"nilsenj/toastr-5.1-laravel": "dev-master"`

**I have added CSS and JS**

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" 
  href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/css/toastr.css">
<script 
  src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/toastr.js/latest/js/toastr.min.js">
</script>
```

And in controller i have added message like

```
Toastr::success('Messages in here', 'Title', 
        ["positionClass" => "toast-top-center"]);
```

But *toastr message* not display.

Comment: any error/warning you are getting   ??

Answer (score 2):

Did you add this in your master template (View) ?

```
{!! Toastr::render() !!}
```

Comment: Yes,  i have added this but still not working and i have use name space like use nilsenj\Toastr\Facades\Toastr;

Comment: if we redirect the page then workign. otherwise not working